# Submit button not working and redirecting to 404 error page in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have deployed Django in my site subdomain apps.example.com through cPanel and the home page of my Django app apps.example.com/adsense-eligibility-checker is working but when I fill the form and click on the ***SUBMIT***  Button it redirects to 404 error page instead of running the second function ***scanned(requests)*** in mainApp/views.py. But it works in local host.

This is inside mainApp/views.py directory:

```
    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'home.html')
        
    
    def scanned(request):
        email = request.POST['email']
        site = request.POST['site']
        rating = request.POST['stars']
        source = request.POST.getlist('source')
......
        return render(request, "result.html", {'rMsg':rMsg,'result0':result0, 'result1':result1,'site': site,'show_site':show_site, 'vips':m1, 'domain':domain, 'site_age':site_age, 'sent': sent})
```

Inside MainApp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from.import views

urlpatterns=[
    
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('scanned/', views.scanned, name='scanned')

]
```

Inside home.html:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">

  <form method='POST' action="/scanned/" class='FormBody'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id='tab'>
      <h2>Adsense Eligibility Checker</h2>
      <fieldset class='siteAndEmail'>
        <legend>Site & Email</legend>
        <div class='form-wrapper'>
          <div class='full-input'>
            <label for="site">Your Site URL</label>
            <input type="domain" name='site' class='input' placeholder="https://yoursite.com">
          </div>

          <div class='full-input'>
            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
            <input type="text" name='email' class='input' placeholder="youremail@gmail.com">
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class='siteAndEmail reached'>
        <legend>How did you reached us?</legend>
        <label class='c1'>
          <input type="checkbox" name='source' value='Facebook' />
          <i id='icon' class="fa fa-facebook"
            style='background:linear-gradient(white,lightblue); color:dodgerblue;'></i>
          Via Facebook
        </label>
        <label class='c1'>
          <input type="checkbox" name='source' value='Google Search' />
          <i id='icon' class="fa fa-google"
            style='background:linear-gradient(160deg,yellow, dodgerblue,rgb(255, 0, 119), rgb(157, 255, 0)); color:white;'></i>
          Via Google Search
        </label>
        <label class='c1'>
          <input type="checkbox" name='source' value='Quora' />
          <i id='icon' class="fa fa-quora"
            style='background:linear-gradient(rgb(236, 0, 0),rgb(158, 0, 0)); color:white;'></i>
          Via Quora
        </label>
        <div style='display:inline-block;'>
          OTHERS
          <input type="text" name='source'
            style="background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.048);font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace; border:0px; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.568);line-height:1.5em; padding-left:3px;"
            placeholder="others" />

        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <fieldset class='siteAndEmail'>
      <legend>Rate Our Service</legend>
      <div class='rating'>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="stars" value="1" />
          <span class="icon">★</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="stars" value="2" />
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="stars" value="3" checked />
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="stars" value="4" />
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="stars" value="5" />
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
          <span class="icon">★</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset><br>
    <button class='butn'> S C A N </button>


</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Inside result.html:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
{% csrf_token %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style2.css' %}">
<div class='borders'>
<h2>R E S U L T Of Scanning Via Adsense Eligibility Checker</h2>
<div id='result'>
<ul style='text-align:left;'>
    <li type='disc'>
        {{result1}}
        <script>
        if ('{{rMsg}}'== ''){
            document.write('<br>');
            console.log('rMsg Level 1');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('rmsg').innerHTML=('{{rMsg}}');
            console.log('rMsg Level 2');
        }
        
    </script>
    {{result0}}
    <a id='rmsg'></a><br><a alt='What are the pages required for Adsense Approval' title='Pages Required For Adsense Approval' style='display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; color:rgb(196, 255, 87);' href='https://blog.example.com/check-website-eligibility-for-google-adsense/#What_are_the_pages_required_for_Adsense_approval'>
 Pages Required For Adsense Approval
    </a>
</li>
    <li type='disc'>{{domain}}</li>
    <li type='disc'>{{site_age}}</li>
    <p style='text-align:center;'><i id='icon' class="fa fa-globe" style='background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 250, 146, 0.596),rgba(0, 140, 255, 0.637)); color:rgb(255, 255, 255);'></i>
        <a href='{{site}}' style='display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; color:rgb(0, 255, 179);'>{{show_site}}</a> is awesome.
    
    </p>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

<p style='font-size:medium;font-family:serif;'>{{sent}}</p>
<br>
<a style='font-family:Consolas;font-size:larger;font-weight:bolder;display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; color:rgb(196, 255, 87);' href='https://blog.example.com/check-website-eligibility-for-google-adsense/#What_are_the_minimum_requirements_for_Adsense_Approval' title='Minimum requirements for Adsense Approval'>Min-Requirements for Adsense Approval</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Change ```action="/scanned/"``` to ```action="{% url 'scanned' %}"```. What you did is also fine. Better use ```name``` in action. like that instead of hard coded value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last character 'r' of slug `adsense-eligibility-checker` gets vanished into `adsense-eligibility-checke\scanned` and finally, I added `action='adsense-eligibility-checker\scanned'` which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

type attribute also need be added, and action can be left empty if it has to go the current url

```
<button class='butn' type='submit'> S C A N </button>
```

Comment: I have added <button class='butn' type='submit'> S C A N </button>. But it is still not working brother

Answer (score 0):

Change this views.py:

```
    def scanned(request):
        email = request.POST['email']
        site = request.POST['site']
        rating = request.POST['stars']
        source = request.POST.getlist('source')
......
        # Inside function
        return render(request, "result.html", {'rMsg':rMsg,'result0':result0, 'result1':result1,'site': site,'show_site':show_site, 'vips':m1, 'domain':domain, 'site_age':site_age, 'sent': sent})
```

Also, change your action by `name`. Like:

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'scanned' %}" class='FormBody'>
```

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('mainApp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
Is here any mistakes

Comment: It has nothing to do with that... what is the actual url of action??? That the 404 error is showing

Comment: Whenever I use  action="{% url 'scanned' %}" and click on SUBMIT(i.e S C A N) button the url apps.webmatrices.com/adsense-eligibility-checker get transformed into apps.webmatrices.com/adsense-eligibility-checke/scanned, which is good but the 'r' is /adsense-eligibility-checker get vanished into adsense-eligibility-checke(..). What to do

Answer (score 0):

**You have got issues with form url action make that correct and change button type to submit and redirect your url rather than rendering**

```
return redirect('html_page')
```